# Архивация папки без вложенной папки

Tags: 7z, winrar

Я архивирую папку этой командой для `7-Zip`:  `a -tzip -r Test.zip Test -mx=9`
Но архивируется папка с вложенной папкой Test.
Как можно сделать архивацию без вложенной папки?
Для `Winrar` я использую такую команду: `a -ep1 -m5 -r -y Test.rar Test`

Вот как происходит:

```
Test
 - Test.zip
  - Test
   - Files and Dirs
```

Я же хочу сделать такое:

```
Test
 - Test.zip
  - Files and Dirs
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/682961/1106749

Comment: @КириллМалышев, я так понял тут играет команда `-x!test\*` ? попробовал у себя, не сработало